# Should I take the std error of sampling distribution and calculate the z score?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, standard-deviation

Sara Gordon is heading a fund raising drive for a college. She wishes to concentrate on the current 10th reunion class and hopes to get contributions from 36% of the 250 members of that class. Past data indicate that those who contribute to the 10th year reunion will donate 4% of their annual salaries. Sara believes that the reunion class members' average salaries have an avg of 32000 dollars and a std. deviation of 9600 dollars. If her expectations are met (36% of class contributing 4% of their salaries), what is the probability that the reunion gift will be between 110000 dollars and 120000 dollars?

Should I take the std error of sampling distribution and calculate the z score?
If I do that, the z score comes to ~ 6.1

Answer (score 0):

If X is the distribution of the donation,

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{32,000}{25}=1,280$$

$$\sigma_X=\sqrt{\frac{9,600^2}{25^2}}=384$$

Now, if $36\%$ of the 250 guys donate, you have that 90 guys donate.

Lt's Y indicate the distribution of the sum donated, we have

$$\mathbb{E}[Y]=1,280\times 90=115,200$$

$$\sigma_Y=\sqrt{384^2\times 90}\approx3,643$$

As 90 is large enough  you can use the gaussian approx and thus your expected probability is

$$\mathbb{P}[110,000<Y<120,000]=\Phi[\frac{120,000-115,200}{3,643}]-\Phi[\frac{110,000-115,200}{3,643}]=$$

$$=\Phi[1.32]-\Phi[-1.43]\approx 83\%$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand E|X| is 1280 since it should be 4% of the average i.e 32000.I also understand E|Y| and the gaussian approximation part. But could you please help me understand how you arrived at the expression for sigma(x) and sigma(y) ? Is that a formula for standard deviation under certain conditions? Thanks in advance for your patience.

Comment: @ChiNmayBhat : assuming independence the variance of the sum is the sum of variances and $V(aX)=a^2V(X)$

Comment: In sigma(x) why are we using 25^2 as our denominator?

Comment: @ChiNmayBhat $V(aX)=a^2V(X)$ where $a=0.04=\frac{1}{25}$

Comment: Thank you very much!